# Centering a nav bar vertically

Tags: html, css

I have a header with two elements in it. The first is an image that is a company logo and is set to 25% width. The other is a nav bar with its elements set inline so it is horizontal. I'd like for the navigation bar to be set vertically center but for the life of me cant figure it out. I've set everything I know to an element that can use vertical-align and put everything in display inline or table cell to apply it. Nothing works.

Keep in mind that the reason I don't just give it a static percentage padding or margin top is because as the page gets wider the image height expands as the width does so as you expand the browser horizontally the nav becomes more and more out of place.

I would greatly appreciate any help as I've tried ( much longer than i'd like to admit) on just centering an object vertically.

HTML cut down:

```
<div id="container">
<header id="header" role="banner">
    <img src="images" />
    <nav id="nav" role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Biographies">Biographies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Careers">Careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS cut down:

```
header img {
    height: auto;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    }

header nav {
    width: 75%;
    font-size: 1em;
    }

header nav li {
    display: inline-block;

    width: 19%;
    }

header nav li a {
    background: #2CB2E6;
    line-height:
```

Heres a simple jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LbTCT/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here's a fork](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/zW7Xj/) of your original fiddle. You need to be setting `inline-block` on your logo and the `nav` element itself:

```
header img, header nav {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Rather than trying to `float` things.

Comment: Sir, i bow to your greatness.

Comment: Check out [this CSS tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/) for more info on `vertical-align`. It's trickier than it should be for something so seemingly trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing it which involves a small change in your mark-up.

```
<div id="header">
<header role="banner">
    <nav id="navigation" role="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <img src="http://i1207.photobucket.com/albums/bb466/audetwebdesign/jsFiddle%20Demos/chamber-logo.png">
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="About Us">About Us</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Biographies">Biographies</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Services">Services</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Careers">Careers</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

and the CSS looks like:

```
    #header {
        background-color: #cccccc;
        padding: 5px 0;
    }
    header {
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
    header nav {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    header nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    header nav li {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    header nav li img {
        vertical-align: middle;
        border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    header nav li a {
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size: 1.00em;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    }
```

The key is to place the logo image in the first `<li>` element of your list.  You then display all the elements of the list as `inline` and use `vertical-align: middle` to line them up.

You can adjust the padding and margin properties to get the exact look that you need.

Fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/adW9Y/

**NOTE:**
The code also lends itself to allowing the image size to scale with the viewport.

By adding the following CSS rule:

```
.autoSize {
   width: inherit;
}
.autoSize img {
    width: 25%;
}
```

and adding a class to the mark-up as follows:

```
<li class="autoSize">
    <img src="http://i1207.photobucket.com/albums/bb466/audetwebdesign/jsFiddle%20Demos/chamber-logo.png">
</li>
```

Since the `ul` element expands to the width of the view port, you can inherit the width to the child `li` element that wraps the image.  You then set a relative width for the image (25% in this example) and you get the flexible/responsive scaling.

Comment: This is quite neat, but it fails to address one of the requirements of the OP, namely that the image resize according to the viewport width. In this example, it's a fixed size.

Comment: The `inline-block` approach that you used is much more respectful of the original mark-up, so it is the better approach in this case.  Your comment inspired me to review the CSS and the code can allow the image by setting a couple of additional styles, please see NOTE in my post.  I appreciate your feedback, all the best!

Answer (score 0):

The answer regarding putting everything as an inline-block is correct.  The float isn't doing anything for you in that situation other than breaking elements out of document flow.  However, if you're targeting older browsers, here's a solution that should work for those that don't support vertical-align outside of table cells:

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LbTCT/2/)

And the relevant CSS changes are here:

```
header {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
header:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content:" ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
header nav {
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    line-height: 200%;
    margin-top: -2em;
}
```

Comment: With [a bit of tweaking](http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) `inline-block` will work everywhere, including IE6+

Comment: The link you provided is encouraging some semantically incorrect practices, not to mention some outright violations of standard for making the `inline-block` property work that far back.  You shouldn't be putting a `div` inside an `li` element, and you shouldn't have to introduce the old CSS inline hacks to fix IE7.  Aside from the HTML5 elements in the original solution, what I've provided should work back to IE6 without getting too _creative_ with the solution.

Comment: True, older IE needs some hacking (though there's *technically* nothing wrong with a `div` inside a `li`, just might make you feel a bit dirty). Personally, I'd rather use the `inline-block` solution for modern browsers and a conditional stylesheet to get it working in old IE if it's required. Absolute positioning, negative margins and a 200% line-height seem more fragile and hacky to me.